# What is the connection parameter "Use Try Lock" in JBoss 7 trying to lock and sync?

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, database-connection

I have read the documentation about "Use Try Lock" parameter in JBoss connections and it says:

```
<timeout>
    <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
</timeout>
```

### Uses tryLock() instead of lock(). This attempts to obtain the lock for the configured number of seconds, before timing out, rather than failing immediately if the lock is unavailable. Defaults to 60 seconds. As an example, to set a timeout of 5 minutes, set 300.

But I can not find information about why do we need to activate it and what it is trying to sync and lock when it is enable.

In which scenarios do we need to disable or enable this functionality?

Update: For example, If I set a negative value

```
<use-try-lock>-1</use-try-lock>
```

we can disable the lock itself, in which scenario we can disable the lock safely? and in which scenarios we need the lock enable? what is the main purpose of having the lock enable?

Comment: As per the text you posted above - Lock : fails immediately if it can not get the lock ; tryLock: will try for x seconds before failing to get lock

Comment: Agree, but what is the main purpose of the lock, what is jboss trying to sync? and when do we need to disable or enable the lock?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found information about what is this lock used for:
[jdbc connection wrapper lock](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6587)

Basically, a jdbc connection needs to be threadsafe for all operations that are performed with the connection.

The only remaining question would be: what are the consequences of turning this feature off by using a negative value in the parameter?